# Import Users into Joomla 1.6 via CSV

Tags: csv, import, joomla, joomla1.6

I am currently working with a Joomla 1.6 install and need to import about 500+ users from a completely separate database. Here's my dilemma:

I downloaded the DB as a CSV file, but the passwords are all just standard passwords, no encryption. I know that the passwords stored in the joomla user table is md5 + salt encrypted, so I am wondering how I could go about either importing this CSV into PHPMyAdmin with the correct encrypted password or run the CSV through some sort of extension (not finding many user migration/import extentions for 1.6).

Anyone have any ideas? This is the last thing holding me back from continuing with this project.

Thanks!

Fil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can insert the passwords as a simple MD5 hash, it will still work for letting the user login, though it is recommended to then change the password through the front end system as the salted passwords are more secure. This works for 1.5 and 1.6.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_recover_your_admin_password

http://docs.joomla.org/Resetting_a_user_password